# Postgresql Copy command

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to copy the data from an csv file to table in windows cmd using psql. please find the below cmd which I have used,

```
psql -h localhost -p 5432 -U postgres --dbname postgres -c COPY test FROM 'D:\test\Book1.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;
```

and getting an error: extra command line argument.

Here Im looking for the command which connects to DB and loads the data into DB in a single command.

Thanks.

Comment: You should enclose the command after `-c` and its arguments in double quotes so that Windows interprets them as a single argument.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe: Thank you for the replay,I have done that but its in stand mode doing noting.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe: it worked Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enclose the SQL statement and its arguments in double quotes, like this:

```
psql ... -c "COPY test FROM 'D:\test\Book1.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER"
```

Then it will be passed as a single string to `-c`.